# Is it possible to store a node on a ClipboardContent javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I implemented a drag and drop of a group to a pane putting an empty string in the clipBoard. , this works perfectly but I need my object visible when dragging.

I have seen in some examples that DataFormat is used and that the object should be serializable , well I'm not sure it could work for my case . 
I tried using this method but I got an exception.In fact, JavaFX does not support serialization of components using the Java Serializable interface.

I'm using : JavaSE1.7, JavaFX2.2

Comment: Why are you using a version that has long been out of public support?

Comment: We're working on a suite of projects. For some reasons, we can't upgrade right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image of the `Node` you are dragging and use that for the dragView:

```
private EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onDragDetected() {
    return evt -> {
        Node node = (Node) evt.getSource();
        Dragboard db = node.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
        db.setDragView(createSnapshot(node), evt.getX(), evt.getY());

        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("");
        db.setContent(content);

        evt.consume();
    };
}

private WritableImage createSnapshot(Node node) {
    SnapshotParameters snapshotParams = new SnapshotParameters();
    WritableImage image = node.snapshot(snapshotParams, null);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the method setDragView is since JavaFX 8.0

Comment: Yes it is, I didn't notice.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624491/implement-drag-and-drop-like-in-scene-builder